# How Can I use a custom function's range without Quotation?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, javascript-objects, spreadsheet

I Want To Use `=GETLASTROW(A1:A10)`

instead of `=GETLASTROW("A1:A10")`

i want to get the last row number of a specific range that have values on it ...

Here Is My Custom Function Can You Update This ?

```js
/**
 * Get the last row counts with the blank cells included for a specific range selected.
 *
 * @param {A1:A10} range -->Enter the column number to count on.
 * 
 * @customfunction
 */



function GETLASTROW(range) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();

  var rg = ss.getRange(range).getValues();
  var lrindex;

  for(var i = rg.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    lrindex = i;

    if(!rg[i].every(function(c){ return c == ""; })){
      break;
    }
  }
  return lrindex + 1;
}
```

if you made this then please reply me my updating my code ...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, You can't use it like this `GETLASTROW(A1:A10)` here `A1:A10` Is not a type that JS knows of you need to use one the JavaScript types such as `String, Array, Object`, I think objects is the closest thing for your example you can call the function like this `GETLASTROW({A1:"A10"})`.

Then you can use it like this

```
GETLASTROW({A1:"A10"})

function GETLASTROW(rangeObject){
   var range = rangeObject["A1"] // the value of this will be A10
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand .. can you please update my code with it then i think i can use =GETLASTROW(A1:A10)

instead of =GETLASTROW("A1:A10")